# How to link title of resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

This is what Things look like on my site.

[image: thing]

I want "Cole Haan Air Madison" to actually link to the Cool Haan website where users can purchase that item.

This is the code for the form used to create Things:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@thing, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @thing.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@thing.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this thing from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @thing.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The form visually looks like this:

[image: form]

I know I have to add a link field to the form. But how do I, instead of displaying the link to the user, have it correspond to the title of the Thing?

Here is the show view for Things:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-md-offset-2 col-md-8'>
    <div class='panel panel-default'>
    <div class='panel-heading text-center'>
      <%= image_tag @thing.image.url(:medium) %>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-body'>
    <p>
      <strong><%= @thing.title %></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= @thing.description %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= link_to @thing.user.username, @thing.user %>
    </p>
    <% if @thing.user == current_user %>
      <%= link_to edit_thing_path(@thing) do %>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you wanna do?

Comment: Okay. I want to add a link field to the "New Thing" form. From there, when a Thing is displayed, the title of the Thing should link to where the user type in the form. Is this clearer? @Severin

Comment: are you sure, you are showing right view code to us? Show us `show.html.erb` or is there anything above that `simple_form` code in that view attached?

Comment: Agree with kiddorails.  You are displaying the create view, you need to display the show view code for us to help.

Comment: Sorry guys. I updated the original post with the show view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need [`link_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) tag.

Since, you mentioned:

> I want "Cole Haan Air Madison" to actually link to the Cool Haan
>   website where users can purchase that item.

So, I consider that you are storing `website` of the user's thing.

Replace,

```
<strong><%= @thing.title %></strong>
```

in your code with:

```
<strong><%= link_to @thing.title, @thing.user.website %></strong>
```

Here, `@thing.user` denotes the associated `user` of that thing, and `@thing.user.website` gives back the website of that user.

Comment: Okay, but in order to even have the @thing.website ability, what would I have to add my other files? I've got to update my Thing model, right?

Comment: You had it right before your last edit. I would use @thing.website, since I suppose website would be the name of the form field used to type the link of the website in.

Comment: I saw you `@thing.user` in your view code, so I think you are already using association b/w a thing and a user. And logically, a user must have a website, so I changed the code to reflect that.

Comment: @DylanRichards : Oh. Do it in the way you want your application to respond :). Key here was to point you where to change the code, and with what syntax. :)